# How do I use kombu with pika async?

Tags: asynchronous, rabbitmq, pika, kombu

I'm trying to use kombu to write a server that will process two messages at the same time. My transport is rabbitmq.

I believe the answer is to use kombu with pika-async. However, there doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to do this.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

You should use gevent or eventlet to make all the calls async.